# Hermitian operator and numerical range

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove that for a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ an operator $T:\mathcal H \to \mathcal H$ is hermitian if and only if it's numerical range $W(T)$ is real, where $W(T)=\{\langle Tx,x \rangle \ : \ ||x||=1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W(T)$ is real, $\langle Tx, x\rangle$ is real for all $x$.  Thus $$\langle Tx, x\rangle = \overline{\langle Tx, x\rangle} = \langle x, Tx \rangle = \langle T^* x, x \rangle $$
so $\langle (T - T^*) x, x\rangle = 0$.
Now use the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) for the inner product $(x,y) \to \langle (T - T^*) x, y\rangle$.